# Unable to understand Bitwise & operator in java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
int number = 3;
System.out.println(number & 1 << 2);
```

Given this snippet where I am performing bitwise AND to number and then left shifting by 2, Why is the result 0 and not 4 (0100)?

Comment: "I am performing bitwise AND to number and then left shifting by 2" that's not the order of the operations. Shifting has higher precedence than bitwise `&`.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). This is equivalent to `number & (1 << 2)`, not `(number & 1) << 2`

Comment: What you learn from this question: better use an extra set of parentheses in situations like this, for safety and readability.

Answer (score 2):

Make it **(number & 1) << 2** because what you are doing means shift 1 << 2 times and then & that with number.

Answer (score 2):

First, as multiple people have already mentioned, the & operator's precedence is smaller than <<'s. So your code would look like this: `number & (1 << 2)`. Let's imagine your code looked like this instead: `(number % 1) << 2`. Now, what does this do?

First, let's talk about the & operator. What does it do? In short, it will apply an AND gate to each bit of the two given numbers, recording the result of the gate in a new number:

```
a      0 0 1 1
b      1 1 1 0
result 0 0 1 0
```

An AND gate works in the following way: the result of this gate is 1 only when both inputs are 1, otherwise, the output of the gate is 0.

In your case, you have the following:

```
a         ...number
b   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Since each bit but the first one of `b` is 0, the result will be all 0s, except for the first bit, which will be whatever the first bit of `number` was (note that `a & 1` is virtually equivalent to `a % 2`).

The shift operator now will shift the only remaining bit to the left 2 bits, which will virtually multiply it by 4.

So, for example, if `number` was 3, 3 & 1 would be 1 (the first bit of 3 is 1), and then 1 would be shifted over 2 bits, so the result would be 4.

In fact, the expression `(number & 1) << 2` will produce only two values:

- 4, when the number is odd (its first bit is 1)
- 0, when the number is even (its first bit is 0)